# How to get DateTime with MilliSecond in EntityFramework C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I am new to Entity Framework.I am getting data from .edmx file.
My issue is when I am fetching date,I am only getting DateTime without Millisecond.I have also set precision to 3.

How can I get DateTime with Millisecond like 19-sept-2014 4:46:10.234 ?

```
var objProduct = (from p in Products
                   where p.productId == 5
                   Select p);
```

thanks

Comment: Are you storing that `DateTime` with seconds/miliseconds?

Comment: I want to store datetime with Milliseconds.I am getting datetime with second but I also want Millisecond.

Comment: But, in the DB row, are these miliseconds present?

Comment: Yes in the DB Millisecond preset

Comment: Actually I don't know how to assist you because who knows what's going on in your code. You should provide some sample code..

Comment: Just simple (from v in products select v;)

Comment: wow what a sample code :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61557/discussion-between-sandy-and-matias-fidemraizer).

Comment: Provide the code in your question! You don't need a private chat :D